# Microsoft reports and crystal reports could not be downloaded as PDF file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report, rdlc

when ever i try to download the reports in my MVC application , it can't be downloaded as PDF file but it can be downloaded as excel , word and XML file 
please any solution

Comment: You gotta give a lot more information than that for anyone here to be able to help. Please look, in the Help section of this website, about how to ask a good question. Kindly give details of your code or your environment or mention how others can re-create the problem, before they can offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a Browser behavior (open instead of save as pdf) issue.
Consider providing more details in your question.